# How to find a JNDI resource inside the hibernatetool Ant task

Tags: mysql, hibernate, ant, hbm2ddl

I want to generate my database schema with Ant. I am using hbm2ddl task.

I am using Hibernate with JNDI. My hibernate.cfg.xml looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/my_app</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

            <!-- Mapping -->   
  </session-factory>  
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/myapp/META-INF/context.xml looks like:

```
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/my_app" 
            global="jdbc/my_app"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
            username="userA"
            password="userA123"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myapp?autoReconnect=true"
            maxActive="8" 
            maxIdle="4"/>
</Context>
```

And inside $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/web.xml I have:

```
     <resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/my_app</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Inside **build.xml** I have the next target.

```
<target name="schema" description="Generate DB schema from the O/R mapping files">
    <hibernatetool destdir="${basedir}">
        <classpath path="${java.src.home}">
          <fileset dir="${java.src.home}">
                  <include name="**/*.hbm.xml"/>
          </fileset>
        </classpath>
    <configuration configurationfile="${java.src.home}/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>         
        <hbm2ddl 
            drop="true" 
            create="true"
            export="true"
            outputfilename="myapp-ddl.sql"
            delimiter=";"
            format="true"/>       
    </hibernatetool>
</target>
```

The problem is that ant is not finding the Resource element stored in context.xml.

```
[hibernatetool] Error #1: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not find datasource
```

I tried, without success, to add the nex snippet inside the classpath element.

```
 <fileset dir="${web.home}/META-INF">
       <include name="context.xml"/>
   </fileset>
```

**How can i point Ant to find the Resource defined in context.xml?**

I post a complete error stacktrace.

```
[hibernatetool] INFO: JNDI InitialContext properties:{}
[hibernatetool] java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
[hibernatetool]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
[hibernatetool]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)
[hibernatetool]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.getResourceURL(AntClassLoader.java:1014)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader$ResourceEnumeration.findNextResource(AntClassLoader.java:146)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader$ResourceEnumeration.<init>(AntClassLoader.java:108)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findResources(AntClassLoader.java:958)
[hibernatetool]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:1016)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12$5.run(VersionHelper12.java:149)
[hibernatetool]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.getResources(VersionHelper12.java:146)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.ResourceManager.getApplicationResources(ResourceManager.java:468)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.ResourceManager.getInitialEnvironment(ResourceManager.java:159)
[hibernatetool]     at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:219)
[hibernatetool]     at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:175)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.util.NamingHelper.getInitialContext(NamingHelper.java:28)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.configure(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:52)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:124)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:56)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.java:27)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:180)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:133)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.ant.Hbm2DDLExporterTask.execute(Hbm2DDLExporterTask.java:55)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask.execute(HibernateToolTask.java:171)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
[hibernatetool]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
[hibernatetool]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[hibernatetool]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:105)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1329)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1298)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[hibernatetool]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1181)
[hibernatetool]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:423)
[hibernatetool]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:137)
[hibernatetool] java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
[hibernatetool]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
[hibernatetool]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)
[hibernatetool]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.getResourceURL(AntClassLoader.java:1014)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader$ResourceEnumeration.findNextResource(AntClassLoader.java:146)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader$ResourceEnumeration.<init>(AntClassLoader.java:108)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findResources(AntClassLoader.java:958)
[hibernatetool]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:1016)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12$5.run(VersionHelper12.java:149)
[hibernatetool]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.getResources(VersionHelper12.java:146)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.ResourceManager.getApplicationResources(ResourceManager.java:468)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.ResourceManager.getInitialEnvironment(ResourceManager.java:159)
[hibernatetool]     at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:219)
[hibernatetool]     at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:175)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.util.NamingHelper.getInitialContext(NamingHelper.java:28)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.configure(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:52)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:124)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:56)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.java:27)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:180)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:133)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.ant.Hbm2DDLExporterTask.execute(Hbm2DDLExporterTask.java:55)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask.execute(HibernateToolTask.java:171)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
[hibernatetool]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
[hibernatetool]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[hibernatetool]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:105)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1329)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1298)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[hibernatetool]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1181)
[hibernatetool]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:423)
[hibernatetool]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:137)
[hibernatetool] java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
[hibernatetool]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
[hibernatetool]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)
[hibernatetool]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.getResourceURL(AntClassLoader.java:1014)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader$ResourceEnumeration.findNextResource(AntClassLoader.java:146)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader$ResourceEnumeration.<init>(AntClassLoader.java:108)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findResources(AntClassLoader.java:958)
[hibernatetool]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:1016)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12$5.run(VersionHelper12.java:149)
[hibernatetool]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.getResources(VersionHelper12.java:146)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.ResourceManager.getApplicationResources(ResourceManager.java:468)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.ResourceManager.getInitialEnvironment(ResourceManager.java:159)
[hibernatetool]     at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:219)
[hibernatetool]     at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:175)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.util.NamingHelper.getInitialContext(NamingHelper.java:28)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.configure(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:52)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:124)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:56)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.java:27)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:180)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:133)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.ant.Hbm2DDLExporterTask.execute(Hbm2DDLExporterTask.java:55)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask.execute(HibernateToolTask.java:171)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
[hibernatetool]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
[hibernatetool]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[hibernatetool]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:105)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1329)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1298)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[hibernatetool]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1181)
[hibernatetool]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:423)
[hibernatetool]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:137)
[hibernatetool] java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
[hibernatetool]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
[hibernatetool]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)
[hibernatetool]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.getResourceURL(AntClassLoader.java:1014)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader$ResourceEnumeration.findNextResource(AntClassLoader.java:146)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader$ResourceEnumeration.<init>(AntClassLoader.java:108)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findResources(AntClassLoader.java:958)
[hibernatetool]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:1016)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12$5.run(VersionHelper12.java:149)
[hibernatetool]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.getResources(VersionHelper12.java:146)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.ResourceManager.getApplicationResources(ResourceManager.java:468)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.ResourceManager.getInitialEnvironment(ResourceManager.java:159)
[hibernatetool]     at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:219)
[hibernatetool]     at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:175)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.util.NamingHelper.getInitialContext(NamingHelper.java:28)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.configure(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:52)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:124)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:56)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.java:27)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:180)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:133)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.ant.Hbm2DDLExporterTask.execute(Hbm2DDLExporterTask.java:55)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask.execute(HibernateToolTask.java:171)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
[hibernatetool]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
[hibernatetool]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[hibernatetool]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:105)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1329)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1298)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[hibernatetool]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1181)
[hibernatetool]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:423)
[hibernatetool]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:137)
[hibernatetool] java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
[hibernatetool]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
[hibernatetool]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)
[hibernatetool]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.getResourceURL(AntClassLoader.java:1014)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader$ResourceEnumeration.findNextResource(AntClassLoader.java:146)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader$ResourceEnumeration.<init>(AntClassLoader.java:108)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findResources(AntClassLoader.java:958)
[hibernatetool]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:1016)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12$5.run(VersionHelper12.java:149)
[hibernatetool]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.getResources(VersionHelper12.java:146)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.ResourceManager.getApplicationResources(ResourceManager.java:468)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.ResourceManager.getInitialEnvironment(ResourceManager.java:159)
[hibernatetool]     at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:219)
[hibernatetool]     at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:175)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.util.NamingHelper.getInitialContext(NamingHelper.java:28)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.configure(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:52)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:124)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:56)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.java:27)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:180)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:133)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.ant.Hbm2DDLExporterTask.execute(Hbm2DDLExporterTask.java:55)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask.execute(HibernateToolTask.java:171)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
[hibernatetool]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
[hibernatetool]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[hibernatetool]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:105)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1329)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1298)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[hibernatetool]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1181)
[hibernatetool]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:423)
[hibernatetool]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:137)
[hibernatetool] java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
[hibernatetool]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
[hibernatetool]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)
[hibernatetool]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.getResourceURL(AntClassLoader.java:1014)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader$ResourceEnumeration.findNextResource(AntClassLoader.java:146)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader$ResourceEnumeration.<init>(AntClassLoader.java:108)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findResources(AntClassLoader.java:958)
[hibernatetool]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:1016)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12$5.run(VersionHelper12.java:149)
[hibernatetool]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.getResources(VersionHelper12.java:146)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.ResourceManager.getApplicationResources(ResourceManager.java:468)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.ResourceManager.getInitialEnvironment(ResourceManager.java:159)
[hibernatetool]     at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:219)
[hibernatetool]     at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:175)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.util.NamingHelper.getInitialContext(NamingHelper.java:28)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.configure(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:52)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:124)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:56)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.java:27)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:180)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:133)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.ant.Hbm2DDLExporterTask.execute(Hbm2DDLExporterTask.java:55)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask.execute(HibernateToolTask.java:171)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
[hibernatetool]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
[hibernatetool]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[hibernatetool]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:105)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1329)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1298)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[hibernatetool]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1181)
[hibernatetool]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:423)
[hibernatetool]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.ui.antsupport.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:137)
[hibernatetool] java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
[hibernatetool]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
[hibernatetool]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)
[hibernatetool]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.getResourceURL(AntClassLoader.java:1014)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader$ResourceEnumeration.findNextResource(AntClassLoader.java:146)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader$ResourceEnumeration.<init>(AntClassLoader.java:108)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findResources(AntClassLoader.java:958)
[hibernatetool]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:1016)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12$5.run(VersionHelper12.java:149)
[hibernatetool]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.getResources(VersionHelper12.java:146)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.ResourceManager.getApplicationResources(ResourceManager.java:468)
[hibernatetool]     at com.sun.naming.internal.ResourceManager.getInitialEnvironment(ResourceManager.java:159)
[hibernatetool]     at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:219)
[hibernatetool]     at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:175)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.util.NamingHelper.getInitialContext(NamingHelper.java:28)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.configure(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:52)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:124)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:56)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.java:27)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:180)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:133)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.ant.Hbm2DDLExporterTask.execute(Hbm2DDLExporterTask.java:55)
[hibernatetool]     at org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask.execute(HibernateToolTask.java:171)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
[hibernatetool]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
[hibernatetool]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[hibernatetool]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:105)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1329)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1298)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultE
```

Comment: This is a good question.  I am curious to know the answer to this!

Comment: Hopefully, someone answers soon

Comment: You may want to ask this on the Hibernate forums and post the answer back here.

Comment: I am attempting to find the answer also, I came across this but it wasn't much help:
http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17080.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do that. Ant can't refer to the configuration you put inside tomcat, as it runs outside the container.

To generate the schema from ant, use another hibernate.cfg.xml file that specify connection parameters instead of a JNDI.